# Marker Clustering doesn't work in Mapbox sdk 1.0.11

Tags: android, maps, native, mapbox, markerclusterer

I'm implementing Marker clustering in my app. I use mapbox sdk 1.0.11, I have three issues here .

1. when Clusters which overlay one on top of other, `mMapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener` doesn't work.
2. disabling the rotation of the map `mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);`
   mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setRotationEnabled(false);`
   doesn't work.
3. It gives an unknown error regularly , here is the log

   `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.nativeRenderSync(Native Method) at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.NativeMapView.renderSync(NativeMapView.java:141)
   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:1260) at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16068)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)`

   Can someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I use mapbox sdk 1.0.11

The latest version of the Mapbox Android SDK is 4.1.1. I'd recommend upgrading to this version, you can find the installation instructions [here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-sdk/#gradle).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @zugaldia. I would love to update to mapbox Sdk 4.1.1. Hopefully it should fix all my issues.

I have recently update to map box idk 1.1.1, this update has fixed all my three issues though.

1.mMapboxMap.setOnMarkerClickListener doesn't work.

**This was a bug in old version. It's fixed in newer version.**

2.disabling the rotation of the map mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false); mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setRotationEnabled(false);`
doesn't work.

**This issue is also fixed and the new methods are
mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(false);
mMapboxMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(false);**

3.**This issue is also fixed in new version.**